# Input field values are null in bean action method

Tags: jsf

The input field boxes are filled with `#{ad.userid}` like that in all pages. And even though when I enter valid values they are giving  `null` values in managed bean when accessed in action method. How can this happen and how can I solve this?

Comment: please take your time to give the necessary details and structure your question in a more readable way.

Comment: Hint: Do not assume the same people that answered your previous question will also see this one. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by unnecessarily having `immediate="true"` in `h:commandButton`, or by using `rendered`, `disabled` or `readonly` attributes in the input fields (or one of its parent components) which are depending on a request scoped bean which isn't properly retained in the subsequent request. There are more possible causes, but that's too much to be mentioned. The aforementioned are at least the most common causes among starters.

To learn more about the JSF lifecycle so that you can get a better understanding of what's all happening "under the hoods" so that you can nail it better down yourself, check this article: [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Indeed, I used "disabled" and the orchestration between a former on blur ajax event and a latter onclick commandbutton event didn't work appropriately. I got rid of disabled and it worked as usual (described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596558/primefaces-6-0-inputtext-ajax-event-commandbutton-event-yields-null-bean-fie).

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. In my case I had these imports in place in my bean:

```java
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "fooBean")
@RequestScoped
public class FooBean {
...
}
```

instead of these:

```java
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9921449/4402950

Comment: Nice answer! Solved my problem, that was exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing somthing like this and it was solved when I used

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="componenet_ID" process="@form" listener="#{ManagedBeen.action}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the input values were null, because the object were replace by other object by the aplication. So, we were submiting another object.

We were working in a dynamic lazy list, so we had that issue.