# @javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty in CDI @Named bean returns null

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean, managed-property

I'm trying to deal with `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty` but without success !

I've been following [this](http://balusc.blogspot.it/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther) guide, and it not seems that hard.
But my code simply won't work!

Here's a little snippet

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private User user;

    // ...
}
```

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MessagesBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginBean}")
    private LoginBean loginBean;

    public String getUser() {
        System.err.println(loginBean == null);
        return loginBean.getUser().getUsername();
    }

    // ...
}
```

This code gives me a `NullPointerException`, saying that `loginBean` is null!

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does @EJB annotation automatically inject the bean, or how do you inject them to LoginBean ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are mixing JSF managed beans with CDI beans. Your *LoginBean* is a JSF managed bean (it has the `@ManagedBean` annotation). Your *MessageBean* is a CDI bean (it has the `@Named` annotation). If you changed the Message bean to a JSF managed bean (replacing `@Named` with `@ManagedBean`) then the problem should be solved (It should work with two CDI beans as well). Or if you're using JSF 2.3 or newer, then use [`javax.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/annotation/ManagedProperty.html) instead in the CDI bean.

Here is a short overview of how injection works between both bean types:

CDI @Named --> CDI @Named (works)

CDI @Named --> JSF @ManagedBean (works only if scope of injected bean is broader)

JSF @ManagedBean --> JSF @ManagedBean (works only if scope of injected bean is broader)

JSF @ManagedBean --> CDI @Named (won't work)

But take care of the scope import classes. There are different classes for `@SessionScoped` and `@RequestScoped` depending on the bean type.

> `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` for @ManagedBeans

> `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` for CDI @Named beans

In addition, for `@Named` (CDI) use `@Inject` and for `@ManagedBean` use `@ManagedProperty`. There is one thing that does not work in CDI. Your `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginBean}")` gets a full bean, but `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginBean.user}")` to get a 'property' of a bean works to. This is not directly possible in CDI with `@Inject`. See [CDI Replacement for @ManagedProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934458/cdi-replacement-for-managedproperty) for a 'solution'

Comment: Great, thanks !
I already tried replacing `@Named` with `@ManagedBean`, but I had the wrong `@RequestScoped` annotation import, so it didn't work!

Comment: Why not go the other way arround? CDI managed beans provide more flexibility and can do everything your JSF ManagedBeans can. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/jsf-backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named

Comment: @JanM I'm switching from managedbean to named. Any chance you know if I have to change EJB to Inject and ManagedProperty to Inject aswell ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ced You don't have to switch `@EJB` for `@Inject` but `@ManagedProperty` should only be used from JSF managed beans and therefore not used in pure CDI context, so replace them with `@Inject`.