# CDI Replacement for @ManagedProperty

Tags: jsf, cdi, inject, managed-property

I'm trying to convert some code from Richfaces 4 showcase to use CDI instead of JSF annotations.

I understand that I can use `@Named` to replace `@MangedBean` and `@Inject` to replace `@ManagedProperty`.  But I'm having some trouble.  I'm trying to convert the RichFaces Tree example specifically.

I have made the following changes and I know this is not correct so please don't use this:

```
//@ManagedBean
//@ViewScoped
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{cdsParser.cdsList}")
//    private List<CDXmlDescriptor> cdXmlDescriptors;
    @Inject
    private Instance<CDXmlDescriptor> cdXmlDescriptors;
// I also Tried :
//  @Inject
//    private CDParser cdsParser;
//    private List<CDXmlDescriptor> cdXmlDescriptors = cdsParser.getCdsList();

........
```

Then I added (and I'm not sure this is needed):

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CDXmlDescriptor implements Serializable { ...
```

and changed:

```
//@ManagedBean(name = "cdsParser")
@Named("CDParser")
//@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CDParser implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3890828719623315368L;
    @Named
    private List<CDXmlDescriptor> cdsList;
```

I cannot figure out the proper way to replace `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{cdsParser.cdsList}")` using CDI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On JSF 2.3+ you can use [`javax.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/annotation/ManagedProperty.html) for this. It works the same way as the old and since JSF 2.3 deprecated [`javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html), you only need to add `@Inject` to it.

Example:

```
import javax.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty;
...
@Inject
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{cdsParser.cdsList}")
private List<CDXmlDescriptor> cdXmlDescriptors;
```

If you're not on JSF 2.3+ yet, then you need a [producer field](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#d0e1022) or a [producer method](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#d0e948) to make it injectable.

Example for producer field:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
...
@Named 
@Produces 
private List<CDXmlDescriptor> cdsList;
```

Example for producer method:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

private List <CDXmlDescriptor> cdsList;
...
@Named("cdsList") 
@Produces 
public List<CDXmlDescriptor> getCdsList {
  return cdsList;
};
```

This works if there is no other producer field or producer method that returns the same bean type. Otherwise you need to introduce a special qualifier for your producer field to resolve ambiguity:

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;


@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface CdsList {
}
```

with

```
@Named @Produces @CdsList
private List<CDXmlDescriptor> cdsList;
```

Comment: this seems to assume Jboss and not Glassfish...?

Comment: @Thufir This is Java EE 6 and should run on all compliant servers.