# JSF richfaces autocomplete not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, autocomplete, richfaces

I'm using richfaces to get autocomplete but it doesn't work. I studied the richfaces showcases and QA's here but I can't get it to work. I get no error message on the console, the Horse list is not empty, richfaces with AutocompleteBase.js are loaded,

My xhtml:

```
...
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
...
<h:form>
   <rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" minChars="1" 
         autocomopleteMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.autocomplete}"/>           
</h:form>
...
```

My autocomplete Bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class AutoCompleteBean {

private List<String> autocompleteList;
private List<Horse> horses;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        autocompleteList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Hors horse : horses) {
            autocompleteList.add(horse.getName());
        }
    }

    public List<String> autocomplete(String prefix) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Iterator<Horse> it = autocompleteList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            if (it.next().getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
                result.add(it.next());
            }   
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

[HTML output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP6VE.png)

Comment: Is there anyting inside your horses array?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* Please elaborate problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. Stack Overflow is to support website developers, not website endusers. E.g. which lines of Java code are (un)expectedly executed, which (un)expected values do the variables hold, how does the HTTP payload look like, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `autocompleteMethod` not `autocom**o**pleteMethod`, so:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" minChars="1"
        autocompleteMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.autocomplete}" />
</h:form>
```

Also, check the difference between `@Named` and `@ManagedBean` annotations in JSF2.0 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994158/difference-between-named-and-managedbean-annotations-in-jsf2-0-tomcat7).

Whole modified code:

```
@ManagedBean // instead of @Named
@RequestScoped
public class AutoCompleteBean {

    // sample initialization, ensure that the list has some values
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{someOtherBean.myHorses}")
    private List<Horse> horses;
    private List<String> autocompleteList;

    public List<String> autocomplete(String prefix) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // don't use iterators unless you really need it
        // also, you had errors in this part (it.next)
        for (String s : autocompleteList) {
            if (s.startsWith(prefix)) {
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for (Horse horse : horses) {
            autocompleteList.add(horse.getName());
        }
    }

    public void setHorses(List<Horse> horses) {
        this.horses = horses;
    }
}
```

If you are using `faces-config.xml` instead of annotations, then it should be:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>autoCompleteBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>sample.package.AutoCompleteBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>horses</property-name>
        <value>#{someOtherBean.myHorses}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: @JohnA you're welcome. Use IDE to help you. Every well known Java EE IDE has content assist which will help you avoid such a typos in future.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `it.next()` twice in what should be a single iteration, every time you call that method you'll get a different element.

Comment: Even though, he should get every second result :D

Comment: @JohnA you have `it.next().getName().startsWith(prefix)` and `result.add(it.next())`. The name that you've checked is not the same name you're adding to the result.