# p:dataTable single row selection

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem selecting a row from a datatable in PrimeFaces. My selected object in the managed bean is null. For some reason, selected object from the datatable is not setting up correctly the property selectedItinerary in my managed bean.

```
   <p:dataTable id="singleDT" value="#{travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean.searchList}" var="s"  selectionMode="single" selection="#{travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean.selectedItinerary}" rowKey="#{s.iden}" >

                                <f:facet name="header">  
                                    Found itineraries
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:column headerText="Departure Location">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{s.departureLocation}" />  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Arrival Location">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{s.arrivalLocation}" />  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Departure Date">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{s.departureDate}" />  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Cost">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{s.cost}" />  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Stops">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{s.stopPrint}"   />  
                                </p:column>
                                <f:facet name="footer">
                                    <p:commandButton process="singleDT" value="Reserve itinerary" action="#{travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean.reserveFlight()}" />
                                </f:facet>

      </p:dataTable>
```

and the managed bean is like this:

```
@Named(value = "travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean{


@EJB
private itineraryTravellerFacadeLocal itineraryTravellerFacade;

@EJB
private itineraryFacadeLocal itineraryFacade;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{travellerLoginManagedBean}")
private travellerLoginManagedBean loginBean;
private String departureLocation;
private String arrivalLocation;
private Date departureDate;
private int departureHour;
private int departureMinute;
private int numPassengers;
private int maxStops;
private String economyOrBusiness;
private ArrayList<itineraryDTO> itinerariesList;
private ArrayList<itineraryTraveller> searchList;
private itineraryTraveller selectedItinerary;
private String stopPrint;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean.class.getName());



public String getStopPrint() {
    return stopPrint;
}

public travellerLoginManagedBean getLoginBean() {
    return loginBean;
}



public void setLoginBean(travellerLoginManagedBean loginBean) {
    this.loginBean = loginBean;
}

public void setStopPrint(String stopPrint) {
    this.stopPrint = stopPrint;
}

public itineraryTraveller getSelectedItinerary() {
    return selectedItinerary;
}

public void setSelectedItinerary(itineraryTraveller selectedItinerary) {
    this.selectedItinerary = selectedItinerary;
}

public ArrayList<itineraryTraveller> getSearchList() {
    return searchList;
}

public void setSearchList(ArrayList<itineraryTraveller> searchList) {
    this.searchList = searchList;
}

public ArrayList<itineraryDTO> getItinerariesList() {
    return itinerariesList;
}

public void setItinerariesList(ArrayList<itineraryDTO> itinerariesList) {
    this.itinerariesList = itinerariesList;
}

public itineraryFacadeLocal getItineraryFacade() {
    return itineraryFacade;
}



public String getEconomyOrBusiness() {
    return economyOrBusiness;
}

public void setEconomyOrBusiness(String economyOrBusiness) {
    this.economyOrBusiness = economyOrBusiness;
}



public void setItineraryFacade(itineraryFacadeLocal itineraryFacade) {
    this.itineraryFacade = itineraryFacade;
}


public String getDepartureLocation() {
    return departureLocation;
}

public void setDepartureLocation(String departureLocation) {
    this.departureLocation = departureLocation;
}

public String getArrivalLocation() {
    return arrivalLocation;
}

public void setArrivalLocation(String arrivalLocation) {
    this.arrivalLocation = arrivalLocation;
}

public Date getDepartureDate() {
    return departureDate;
}

public void setDepartureDate(Date departureDate) {
    this.departureDate = departureDate;
}

public int getDepartureHour() {
    return departureHour;
}

public void setDepartureHour(int departureHour) {
    this.departureHour = departureHour;
}

public int getDepartureMinute() {
    return departureMinute;
}

public void setDepartureMinute(int departureMinute) {
    this.departureMinute = departureMinute;
}

public int getNumPassengers() {
    return numPassengers;
}

public void setNumPassengers(int numPassengers) {
    this.numPassengers = numPassengers;
}

public int getMaxStops() {
    return maxStops;
}

public void setMaxStops(int maxStops) {
    this.maxStops = maxStops;
}

public travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean() {
}

public void searchFlights(){

    try{
        int numPassengersEconomy=0;
        int numPassengersBusiness=0;
        if (economyOrBusiness.equals("Economy")){
            numPassengersEconomy=numPassengers;
        }else{
            numPassengersBusiness=numPassengers;
        }

        searchList = new ArrayList<itineraryTraveller>();
        itinerariesList= new ArrayList<itineraryDTO>();
        int id=itineraryFacade.findItineraries(itinerariesList,departureLocation, arrivalLocation,departureDate,numPassengersEconomy, numPassengersBusiness);
        searchList=itineraryFacade.listItineraries(maxStops,itinerariesList,arrivalLocation, departureLocation, numPassengersEconomy, numPassengersBusiness);
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {}

}


public void reserveFlight(){
    //if (){
    try{

        //status reserved when traveller reserves an itinerary
        selectedItinerary.setStatus('r');
        //set the userName from the user who reserved this itinerary before persist it in a shared among all users db

        //persist the reserved itinerary in the db
        itineraryTravellerFacade.create(selectedItinerary);

     } catch(NullPointerException e) {}
}
```

}

Comment: Try with @ViewScoped

Comment: If I change it to ViewScoped, a javax.faces.FacesException is produced

Comment: Yes, what does it say in the log? What package did you import from?

Comment: show this class please itineraryFacadeLocal

Comment: everything works, and the backing bean is working well because it renders the list in the datatable correctly. what is not working is the selectedItinerary

Comment: You're mixing CDI beans and JSF beans, is that on purpose?

Comment: Jaqen, I imported from import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

Comment: not in purpose, how is is wrongly mixed?

Comment: How am I mixing?? everything is CDI (using @named)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921324/managedproperty-in-cdi-named-bean-returns-null

Comment: The import should be import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped; if you want to use CDI (which @Named is)

Comment: OOH THANK YOU (you are right). I now changed to @inject and works well for the injection.

Comment: but that was 50% of the problem, now I have still the problem of selecting the row

Comment: if I change it to viewscoped. I have this exception /travellerLogin.xhtml @24,59 value="#{travellerLoginManagedBean.userName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'travellerLoginManagedBean' resolved to null

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar you were right. It now works with viewscoped. How can I compensate you?

Comment: Great, just happy it worked :-)