# PrimeFaces 6.0 - InputText Ajax event + CommandButton Event Yields NULL Bean Fields

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I want to trigger a method when a text field is blurred, and so I added an Ajax onblur event to this text field, and it works.

The problem I am having is with the commandButton that submits a bean with NULL fields.

When I get rid of the inputText Ajax event, the form submission works as usual.

**The .xhtml file:**
`

```
<h:head>
    <title>Saisie Cotisations</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>Saisie Cotisation</h3>
    <h:form id="formulaire">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="panelMenage" >
                <p:outputLabel value="N° Appartement" for="appart" />
                <p:inputNumber id="appart" value="#{saisieBean.menage.numAppart}" decimalPlaces="0" emptyValue="empty" size="3" thousandSeparator="" >
                    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{saisieBean.chargerMenage}" update="panelMenage panelCotisation"  />
                </p:inputNumber>
                <p:outputLabel value="Nom" for="nom" />
                <p:inputText id="nom" value="#{saisieBean.menage.nom}" disabled="#{saisieBean.lectureSeule}"  >
                </p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="Prenom" for="prenom" />
                <p:inputText id="prenom" value="#{saisieBean.menage.prenom}" disabled="#{saisieBean.lectureSeule}" >
                </p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="Adresse E-Mail" for="email" />
                <p:inputText id="email" value="#{saisieBean.menage.email}" disabled="#{saisieBean.lectureSeule}" >
                </p:inputText>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <br />
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="panelCotisation" >
                <p:outputLabel value="Type Cotisation" />
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{saisieBean.menage.cotisation.id}" disabled="#{saisieBean.lectureSeule}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{saisieBean.typesCotisation}" var="tc" itemValue="#{tc.id}" itemLabel="#{tc.intitule}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:outputLabel value="Mois" />
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{saisieBean.mois}" disabled="#{saisieBean.lectureSeule}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{saisieBean.listeMois}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:outputLabel value="Annee" />
                <p:inputNumber value="#{saisieBean.menage.cotisation.annee}" decimalPlaces="0"  thousandSeparator="" disabled="#{saisieBean.lectureSeule}" />
                <p:outputLabel value="Montant" />
                <p:inputNumber value="#{saisieBean.menage.cotisation.montant}" decimalPlaces="2" disabled="#{saisieBean.lectureSeule}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <br />
        <p:commandButton value="Soumettre" actionListener="#{saisieBean.exec}" process="@form" update="@form" immediate="false" ></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

`

**The Bean:**

```
package ma.syndic.bean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

import ma.syndic.back.bean.Cotisation;
import ma.syndic.back.bean.Menage;
import ma.syndic.back.bean.TypeCotisation;
import ma.syndic.back.dao.bean.MenageDAO;
import ma.syndic.back.dao.bean.TypeCotisationDAO;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
/**
 * 
 * @author  Mohamed ENNAHDI EL IDRISSI
 * @date    13/11/2016
 */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SaisieBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5492998931983521852L;
    private Menage menage;
    private Cotisation cotisation;
    private List<TypeCotisation> typesCotisation;
    private String[] listeMois;
    private String mois;
    private boolean lectureSeule = true;

    public SaisieBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.menage = new Menage();
        this.cotisation = new Cotisation();
        try {
            this.typesCotisation = new TypeCotisationDAO().findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.listeMois = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
        int i = new DateTime().monthOfYear().get();
        this.mois = this.listeMois[ i - 1 ];
        this.menage.getCotisation().setAnnee(new DateTime().year().get());
    }
    public void exec() {
        System.out.println("Exec fired");
        System.out.println("EMail: " + this.menage.getEmail());
    }

    public void chargerMenage() {
        System.out.println("chargerMenage fired");
        if (this.menage.getNumAppart() != null) {
            this.lectureSeule = false;
            try {
                Menage m = new MenageDAO().find(this.menage);
                if (m != null) {
                    this.menage = m;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public Menage getMenage() {
        return menage;
    }
    public void setMenage(Menage menage) {
        this.menage = menage;
    }
    public Cotisation getCotisation() {
        return cotisation;
    }
    public void setCotisation(Cotisation cotisation) {
        this.cotisation = cotisation;
    }

    public List<TypeCotisation> getTypesCotisation() {
        return typesCotisation;
    }

    public void setTypesCotisation(List<TypeCotisation> typesCotisation) {
        this.typesCotisation = typesCotisation;
    }
    public String[] getListeMois() {
        return listeMois;
    }
    public void setListeMois(String[] listeMois) {
        this.listeMois = listeMois;
    }
    public String getMois() {
        return mois;
    }
    public void setMois(String mois) {
        this.mois = mois;
    }
    public boolean isLectureSeule() {
        return lectureSeule;
    }
    public void setLectureSeule(boolean lectureSeule) {
        this.lectureSeule = lectureSeule;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the ajax event update the values correctly?

Comment: Yes. It conditionally changes lectureSeule to false, therefore all other inputs are not disabled anymore.

Comment: I don't know, if it's the problem. But one problem you'll get is, if you fill some input fields and finally enter the appart field. Leaving this field will do an ajax call, which updates all your fields. Your input values are away...

Comment: I am seeing exactly the same issue in PF6.1 with similar code despite what is written in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43753816/69585. The button does not work after ajax event even though it is not included in update.